# Android Studio - Gradle build compiling unversioned class files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I've recently ran into this problem, and would like to know, if possible, whether there's a solution for it.

Basically in the project I'm currently working, there used to be some legacy class files that were deleted in a past commit, but sometimes I need to look them up for quick reference, so I just reverted them back to my local changelist and set them as unversioned.

Now, the problem is that due to the legacy nature of these files, some of them don't compile anymore, but the gradle build attempts to compile them although they're unversioned.

So, my question here is: Is there a way to make gradle ignore unversioned files, just stop contemplating them for the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such way. Gradle cannot exclude files from build based on their version control status. If you only need to use those classes for reference, move them to a directory outside of your project root directory.

Comment: Well, that sucks :/ Thanks for letting me know, though.